# Is there a Javascript "Evoke" function available for <object> - if so, what is it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have inherited a large codebase, mostly in C++; this C++ is creating an HTML page that is being displayed in an Internet Explorer web browser.

The HTML *does not included any Javascript* (.js) files.  There is, in addition, an `<object>` within the HTML; this object seems to be an entirely application-specific, custom object.  Here is the skeleton code for the HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        (Nothing relevant here - no .js files are included)
    </head>
    <body>
        <object
            id=objAppIT
            GUID_START=1 classid="CLSID:D19BF5B4-74E8-437D-8EB0-FCF709C36C77" GUID_END=1
            VER_START=1 codebase="AppIT-Deployer-2,3,1,2.cab#version=2,3,1,2" VER_END=1
        >
            <param name="CFG"
                   value="ACTION=LAUNCH 
                          SID=77cded6b-ddaf-441f-ae4a-d2764d519ab6
                          AID='0000000010000000-00000000000010AC-0005-11-17~05|34|32.149'
                          UID=N/A"
            />
        </object>
        <form id=formSubmit method=post action="valid_url_here">
            (various <input> fields here)
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function()
            {
                var objAppIT = document.getElementById("objAppIT");
                objAppIT.Evoke("LAUNCH", "formSubmit");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code above successfully submits the form - apparently, just as though the form was submitted in the usual fashion (not using the `<object id=objAppIT>`.

I have googled to see if `Evoke()` is a Javascript function that can be called on any `<object>` - because no .js file is included that could otherwise define that function.  I can't find any documentation for `Evoke()`.

Therefore, I do not understand how the above form is submitted.

Hence, my question: Is there a Javascript function `Evoke()`?  If so, what does it do?  If not, I would further appreciate if someone could explain how the above HTML/Javascript snippet is submitting this form.

Comment: There is no such native method. It's being added in somehow.

Comment: It throws an error for me about `Evoke` not existing. The class id does not seem to reveal anything on Google, either. Are you sure the code behind the object is not part of the codebase perhaps? `<object>` elements allow for "custom" functions to be exposed to JavaScript, so it is not necessarily native (probably not here in fact).

Comment: How are the custom functions exposed to Javascript?  Which of the `<object>` parameters provides the information to Javascript about where Javascript should look to locate the custom functions?  Thanks.

Comment: What does the object do? Do you have the source?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening behind the scenes as I can't use the object - could you possibly try searching for the given class id in your codebase?

Comment: Suppose the class ID exists.  Do you know what Javascript is doing to search for that class ID?  Because if it is searching for the class ID, it must be defined within Javascript how to interpret / search for a class ID.  (Perhaps it's an Internet Explorer extension of Javascript?)

Comment: I don't know exactly what JavaScript is doing behind the scenes, but IE does allow embedding objects such as Windows Media Player this way. Have a look here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/d27M7/show/ (just copied from somewhere). You can run `document.getElementById("VIDEO").currentMedia` - WMP related stuff has been exposed through the object to JavaScript. In your case, `Evoke` must exposed by something. I guess it's finding that "something" is necessary to understand what it does...

Answer (score 0):

I also have never heard of an `evoke` function, but it sounds like [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent).

It looks like the `Evoke` function is some user-defined function. We can't tell exactly what it does and what is done with each parameter that is passed into it, but I assume that it takes the second parameter (the ID of the `<form>` element) and submits that using something like this:

```
document.getElementById('formSubmit').submit();
```

Comment: Thank you; I also am guessing that effectively, `submit()` is being called.  However, I want to know how it's possible for a custom function to be defined and available to the browser's running instance of Javascript in this case, given that no .js files are included.  I suspect it may have something to do with the `<object>` parameters.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Sorry, I don't have any experience with HTML objects to be able to answer your question.